# WordPress site with things like AJAX returning 403 (nginx)

Tags: ajax, wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-403, linode

I got a WordPress site up and running on Linode. Followed some guides on installing a LEMP stack and setting up WordPress.

I have run into an issue where any AJAX requests return 403. Stuff for the REST API is also returning 403 errors, so I assume these issues are related.

It's worth mentioning that the website works locally on my MAMP, as well as a testing server on Pantheon. It wasn't until I set up their linode that these problems appeared.

Here is the page in question - https://www.gaudenzia.org/locations/
Check the console and you will see the 403 on https://www.gaudenzia.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Curiously enough, you can go to https://www.gaudenzia.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php directly. It doesn't return a 403 this way for some reason, and instead outputs 0, which is the expected output for a WP AJAX request in this case since we're not POSTing data to it. So it seems to return a 200 in this case, not 403.

**What I Have Tried**

On the server, I have verified that all the files and folders have permissions correctly set to 644 and 755 respectively. They are also set to the correct owner.

Of course, I have tried disabling/deleting plugins on the site.

I've tried a bunch of different modifications to various config files on the server, all to no avail. Basically just googling for something like "nginx wordpress ajax 403" and going through the first 3 pages of results to try possible fixes.

Here's what I have in the sites-available config file (my modifications are commented out):

```
# Trying something to fix AJAX
# from https://givewp.com/documentation/core/frequent-troubleshooting-issues/admin-ajax-blocked/
#add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
#add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

server {
    server_name    gaudenzia.org www.gaudenzia.org;
    root           /var/www/gaudenzia.org/public_html;
    index          index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
     # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args  =404;
      #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
      include         fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gaudenzia.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gaudenzia.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    #include /etc/nginx/common/wpfc-php7.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/common/wpcommon-php7.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/common/locations-php7.conf;

    #include /etc/nginx/common/wp-global-restrictions.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/common/wordpress.conf;

    #include /var/www/gaudenzia.org/nginx_custom/*.conf;
}
server {
    if ($host = www.gaudenzia.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = gaudenzia.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen         80 default_server;
    listen         [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name    gaudenzia.org www.gaudenzia.org;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

I figure there must be some server setting/config thing that I don't know about. I am new to setting up servers (nginx or otherwise).

*** EDIT

**Opera is the problem.**

After all my effort trying to figure out what is wrong with the server, it turns out that the server is not the problem. Realized that the site worked on coworkers' computers. I only encountered the 403 when using Opera. Other browsers work just fine. So it seems like there is something weird about how Opera sends the XHR request to admin-ajax.php, and the server/WordPress returns a 403 as a result. I don't know what Opera is doing to mess this up, but there it is.

Comment: could be CORS? Are you doing any cross-origin requests? Also have you tried changing AJAX dataType to jsonp?

Comment: Cross-origin meaning that I'm loading scripts from other domains? No, nothing related to the AJAX here anyway. There are scripts loading from Google (maps and analytics) and Typekit (fonts) but for the rest it's all on the same domain, same server. I have not tried jsonp for the dataType, I think that will break it if I'm not doing anything cross origin right?

Comment: Could try to inspect the request in "network" tab in chrome and make sure request/response is as expected. Maybe its doing a http -> https or something silly like that

Comment: It's definitely attempting to hit https://www.gaudenzia.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, which is correct.